# Can't execute selenium tests on Windows 10 with parallel_rspec gem

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, rubygems

When I try to execute my selenium tests with parallel_rspec, it says the following error,

```
ChildProcess::MissingFFIError:
  FFI is a required pre-requisite for Windows or posix_spawn support in the ChildProcess gem. Ensure the `ffi` gem is installed. If you believe this is an error, please file a bug at http://github.com/enkessler/childprocess/issues
```

Error's still the same even after installing the ffi gem one version after the another. My Ruby version is 2.6.6, by the way.

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't succeed because I think this works only for Linux not for windows. I have written my own code for parrallel execution.

Comment: Would you mind sharing it ? @Rajagopalan

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to run selenium tests and I get that error, I run

```
gem install ffi
```

and now it's working. I found this issue https://github.com/enkessler/childprocess/issues/169